# how can I replace a string from a specific character with string?

Tags: sed

Using "sed", I would like to replace every "=" and what comes after it to a space.

For example I have this line:

```
VNN=VNN VNNSRAM=VNNSRAM VSS=VSS
```

and I like to change it to:

```
VNN VNNSRAM VSS
```

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you want to delete from the '=' up until the next space? So it's
only a replacement in the sense that you want to replace the string with
nothing? I posted an answer that assumes this, and produces the output in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
sed 's/\=[^ ]\+//g' your_file
```

It matches an '=' sign followed by any non-space character `[^ ]` and checks
that there is at least one or more of them `\+` and removes that part